# How to do input validation simply in C++?

Tags: c++, validation, input

I want to give an error message if the input is neither character `c` nor `h` but I can't get it to work! I looked up some other answers but they mostly use `throw`/`catch` method which I didn't understand at all. I just started programming and error handling is in Chapter 20 or 21. Help me out with the most simple way as possible.

This is what I've tried:

```
cout << "Enter 'c'(even) or 'h'(odd): ";
cin >> your_guess;

if((your_guess != ('c' || 'h')) == false) {
    cout << "Wrong Input. Game is restarting... " << endl;
    // restart the game ...                         
}
```

But it always says `Wrong Input. ...`.

Comment: So what `('c'||'h')` actually evaluates to?

Comment: You already know the simplest way possible--you just tried to use the simple way and made a mistake.  :-)

Comment: It doesn't! I thought it would because the compiler didn't threw error at this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(your_guess != ('c' || 'h')) == false
```

is wrong. **`('c' || 'h')` simply evaluates to `true`**. The [built-in `operator||`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) takes two `bool` arguments:

```
bool operator||(bool, bool)
```

And since `'c'` and `'h'` are both not `NUL` characters, they convert to `true`.
`true` OR `true` is `true`. The language doesn't create some **magical entity** with which you can do `operator==`/`operator!=` with `char` to see if the character is among those you've listed.

Then, later the bool and char are promoted to `int` to do the inequality check. I'd guess `your_guess` won't be equal to `1`. And I don't mean `'1'` (ASCII `49`), but `1` (ASCII `1`). So you've effectively written `if(true)`...

---

What you meant to say is:

```
(your_guess != 'c' || your_guess != 'h') == false
```

or

```
!(your_guess != 'c' || your_guess != 'h')
```

or

```
your_guess == 'c' && your_guess == 'h' // your_guess equal 'c' and 'h' at once?
```

and now you see that **there's something wrong with the logic**.

**The right code for the condition is one of these:**

```
your_guess != 'c' && your_guess != 'h'
!(your_guess == 'c' || your_guess == 'h')
```

It's just [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) all around.

---

#### How to do input validation simply in C++?

If the above is not simple for you, you can use `switch` (because you're probably going to use it anyway). But each `case` tests variable against compile-time constant.

If the letters you want to check for are stored in a variable, I suggest this:

```
std::string valid_characters = "ch"; // this will be our "magical entity"

if(valid_characters.find(your_guess) == std::string::npos)
{
    // you have entered a character that is not 'c' nor 'h'
}
```

Comment: put that last line in bold or bold the line above it.  In my opinion the last line is the clearest answer, and the rest is LogicStuff giving some good feedback and some clues for further learning opportunities.

Comment: @LogicStuff Thank You for your answer but why didn't the compiler threw an error when I had(`c || h`).  Is it like a general rule to always do  `object name!=x || object name!=y`?

Comment: @Sadij It's just that in many programming languages, you don't write expressions the same way you read them in your non-programming language.

Comment: @Sadij As I said, `'c' || 'h'` is `bool`, not a magic object.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
switch(your_guess){
    case 'c' :          
    case 'h'  :
       // do something
       break; 

    default : 
      cout<<"invalid Input"<<endl;
       break; 
}
```

Comment: Thanx! I like this one also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an error message in c++, using cerr instead of cout might be something you may want to think about doing in addition to the changing:

```
your_guess!=('c'||'h'))==false
```

To one of the correct forms listed in the other answers